# Logging out from SPA using Laravel api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I have two applications: SPA built with Vuejs 3 and the API built with Laravel.
the SPA is running on 127.0.0.1:5173 and the api is running on 127.0.0.1:8000
The user can authenticate successfully but I Want logging out it's not working, the user stays authenticated without any error thrown

logout function :

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if(method_exists(auth()->user()->currentAccessToken(), 'delete')) {
            $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        }
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

axios request :

```
 logout() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
              .post('/api/v1/auth/logout')
              .then((response) => {
                resolve(response)
              })
```

logout route :

```
//api.php
Route::prefix('/v1')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    }); 
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using sanctum for your APIs you could do something like this for logging out the user

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


    function logoutout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete(); //to delete the token
        Auth::logout(); //to logout your web
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I have this error `Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not existe `

Comment: and I tried `Auth::guard('web')->logout();` the error does not thrown but the user is not logged out

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and let me know if there is any problem

Comment: same error :( @mohammad

Comment: just for testing could you please change the name of your method from `logout` to something else for example like `logoutsss(Request $request)` and also change your API also and let me know what dose it says

Comment: and also after changing your api please run `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: nothing works :(